# Search string and get below two strings values in same column in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

"detail" has below contents:

```
    1 2 3 4
    a b c
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 status 10
    a b c d e f g h up x
    a b c d e f g h Idle y
```

What I am trying is I need to get value's  below status string in detail contents (up and idle or what ever it has below to status string in next two lines in same column ). In this case up and Idle have in detail contents.

I have tried below method in code

```
     var1, var2 = islice(line, 2)
```

not able to get below two lines output from detail contents.

Please can any one can help me what is best method to achieve this.

Here is the code what i tried

```
from itertools import islice
import string
detail = """1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 status 10
a b c d e f g h up x
a b c d e f g h idle y"""
print detail
for line in detail.split("\n"):
    line = ' '.join(line.split())
    line = line.split(" ")
    print line
    if len(line) >= 9:
        if line[8] == "status":
            var1, var2 = islice(line, 2)
            if any("idle" in s for s in var1.lower()) or any("never" in s for s in var1.lower()):
                print var1[8]
            else:
                print var1[8]
            if any("idle" in s for s in var2.lower()) or any("never" in s for s in var2.lower()):
                print var2[8]
            else:
                print var2[8]
```

Comment: I didn't quite get what it is you are trying to do.. How about posting some of the input as well? Also why `split` then `join` and then `split` again? The second line does not make sense.

Comment: Hi Sir, detail output is the input to split command. Remaining things i will correct it sir

Comment: Can you please not call me sir because it is weird? xD Thanks

Comment: Hi Kounis, I just edited my code removed join and added filter and why i added filter is some times i may get empty values to list. What i am trying is t to get status string below columns output in this case "up" and "idle" in the detail contents

Comment: add a `print` after manipulating the `line` and just before the first `if`. Does the `filter` and `split` do what you expect them to do? Also the indentation level of the first `if` is wrong

Comment: I have corrected code sorry earlier i copied and forgot change.. Yes filter and split is doing what i have expect..you may suggest better way to write my code. purpose of the filter is to remove empty values in the list.